# Using AssetBundleManager to retrieve AssetBundles from a server that requires authentication

Tags: authentication, unity-game-engine, assetbundle

I need to retrieve some AssetBundles that are stored on a remote server. This server requires authentication.

I have been looking into the [`AssetBundleManager`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AssetBundles-Manager.html), which seems an easy way to do that. However, I can't find any way to provide the authentication credentials to the `AssetBundleManager`.

So my question is this. Can I access AssetBundles in a server that requires authentication with the `AssetBundleManager` or do I have to go another way?

In case the second is true. Is using [`UnityWebRequest`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnityWebRequest-DownloadingAssetBundle.html) the only way to pass the authentication credentials in the header of the request?

**EDIT:** As requested in the comments
I am using C#.

The authentication is token authentication (JWT) in the form of

Autorization header: bearer token

Comment: What type of authentication? What language and what have you tried. You can modify your question with these info

Comment: @Programmer Just added the info you suggested

Comment: It sounds like OAuth 2.0 . See answer from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45747010/how-to-get-oauth2-token-with-the-www-api)

Comment: @Programmer Thanks for the tip. Something like this is my plan B. First I want to see (or rule out) the AssetBundleManager since it seems a lot easier. Do you know if I can add an Autorization header to the web request that will happen after this       AssetBundleLoadAssetOperation request = AssetBundleManager.LoadAssetAsync(assetBundleName, assetName, typeof(GameObject) );

Comment: Do you see any parameter you can pass that Authorization header to in the LoadAssetAsync function?