# OAuth2 : How to get authorization code from Outlook API for Authentication in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, oauth-2.0, access-token, outlook-api

I'm developing a desktop application with Unity and I need to check if the user can log in Outlook to have access to my app.

So, I'm following this [process](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/outlook/rest/get-started) from Microsoft docs and I'm trying to figure out how I can open Outlook API login page and send to my app the authorization code and then get the access-token to finally obtained information about the user. I tried several ways but without success.

First, I tried to obtain a kind of AuthenticationContext like We can use in general C# .NET Application by importing some .dlls but It seems that this solution is just a dream.

Then, I tried this [functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43200124/oauth2-authentication-and-operations-in-unity/43202409#43202409) I found, but the issue is that Outlook API, like all Microsoft Authentication API (I guess), needs a redirect_uri to send the code and the access-token. If I can get this authorization's code, I think that I could use the functions I found to do what I need. I tried to set a website with a PHP script as redirect_link to get the code and at the same time, do a request to get it. 
But even if I try to get it through this script with a UnityWebRequest it's not working and It's really an ugly way to do it ^^'

Is there a way to open the Outlook "authorize" page and wait for a response ? Like if I could put the redirect_uri as my desktop application?

I need your help! And is there a better way to do it than mine?

Thanks !

UPDATE :
Here is my C# code

```
private IEnumarator ConnectOutlook()
{
    string client_ID = "client-id";
    string redirect_uri = "link of my PHP script";
    string response_type = "code";
    string url = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=" + client_ID + "&redirect_uri=" + redirect_uri + "&response_type=" + response_type + "&scope=openid";
    Application.OpenURL(url);
    string resultCode = null;
    StartCoroutine(GetAuthorization((code) => resultCode = code));
    yield return new WaitUntil(() => resultCode != null);
StartCoroutine(GetAccessToken(resultCode));
    }

private static IEnumerator GetAuthorization(Action<string> result)
{
    Dictionary<string, string> content = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    content.Add("action", "GetCode");
    UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Post("link of my PHP Script", content);
    //Send request
    yield return www.Send();

    yield return new WaitUntil(() => www.downloadHandler.text != "");
    if (!www.isNetworkError)
    {
        string resultContent = www.downloadHandler.text;
        Debug.Log(resultContent);
         result(resultContent);
    }
    else
    {
        //Return null
        result("");
    }
}

private static IEnumerator GetAccessToken(string code)
    {

        Dictionary<string, string> content = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        //Fill key and value

        content.Add("client_id", "client-id");
        content.Add("client_secret", "client_secret");
        content.Add("code", code);
        content.Add("redirect_uri", "link of my PHP Script");
        content.Add("grant_type", "authorization_code");

        UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Post("https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token", content);
        //Send request
        yield return www.Send();

        if (!www.isNetworkError)
        {
            string resultContent = www.downloadHandler.text;
            TokenClassName json = JsonUtility.FromJson<TokenClassName>(resultContent);

            //Return result
            Debug.Log(json.access_token);
        }
        else
        {
            //Return null
            result("");
        }
    }

public class TokenClassName
{
    public string access_token;
}
```

And here is my PHP Script (Please don't forget I'm trying to not use this script) :

```
<?php
    $code = "";
  // Here I get the code when Outlook API is redirecting after log in
  if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
    //Assign the code 
        $code = $_GET['code'];
  }
  elseif (isset($_GET['error'])) {
    exit('ERROR: '.$_GET['error'].' - '.$_GET['error_description']);
  }

  //Here I try to return the assigned code
  if ($_POST["action"] == "GetCode"){
    echo $_GET['code'];
  } 
?>
```

I'm really looking for a way to disable the redirection to my script. The best should be to use an "await" for a response like in .NET UWP with AuthorizationContext and the way explained [HERE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/datacatalog/authenticate-a-client-app)

Comment: Post the `UnityWebRequest` code that isn't working

Comment: I did it, but for me, It's not an `UnityWebRequest` issue. I'm trying to find a way to get the authorization code after log in from Outlook by "awaiting" the code and without redirect it to a link or, in this case, my ugly/desperate PHP script

Comment: Maybe I forgot something about the possibilities of redirect_uri and I just don't understand how to set it up for a desktop application

Comment: Maybe I don't get your problem. Shouldn't the token be stored in `json.access_token` variable?

Comment: Yes, but my problem is how to get the authorization code I need to get the access token without redirection to a website.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a loopback redirection URL. For example http://localhost:7000/. Just run a listen server inside Unity that will listen to any call of http://localhost:7000/ URL. 
Like

```
TcpListener server = new TcpListener ("http://localhost", 7000);
```

You can also have some random session parameters to ensure http://localhost:7000 is called from the propper session that just started.

Check this git-hub repo with examples: 
https://github.com/zizul/OAuth2.0-Unity/blob/master/Assets/OAuthClient.cs

I've not testes the code. I will update this post after I check it. But it looks like it should work.