# Unable to get authorization code with Unity and OAuth2.0

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory

I'm working in an Unity app that needs to connect to a Microsoft Dynamics 365 which uses OAuth2.0. I was trying using UnityWebRequest to retrieve an access token by calling:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/[TENANT_ID]/oauth2/v2.0/token
```

using something similar to this thread:

[OAuth2 Authentication and Operations in Unity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43200124/oauth2-authentication-and-operations-in-unity)

And it works, I'm able to get and access_token, however, when I try to consume the service with the Bearer token, I always get "401 unauthorized".

I then tried to call instead:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/[TENANT_ID]/oauth2/v2.0/authorize
```

But when I do that, the response is the actual HTML code of the Microsoft login screen. As far I know, getting an auth code requires a user interaction right? but I've been able to get this done by using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory package from NuGet in a console C# app without user interaction, so there must be a way right?

I would really appreciate your help on this! thank you!

**UPDATE 1 - My code**

**Get access token**

```
private IEnumerator GetAccessToken(Action<string> result)
{
    Dictionary<string, string> content = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    //Fill key and value
    content.Add("scope", "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default");
    content.Add("grant_type", "client_credentials");
    content.Add("client_id", "xxxxx");
    content.Add("client_secret", "xxxx");

    UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Post("https://login.microsoftonline.com/[TENANTID]/oauth2/v2.0/token", content);
    //Send request
    yield return www.Send();

    if (!www.isError)
    {
        string resultContent = www.downloadHandler.text;
        TokenClassName json = JsonUtility.FromJson<TokenClassName>(resultContent);

        //Return result
        result(json.access_token);
    }
    else
    {
        //Return null
        result("");
    }
}
```

**Call API**

```
private IEnumerator GetData(Action<string> result)
{
    Dictionary<string, string> content = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    //Fill key and value
    content.Add("CustomerGroupId", "10");

    UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Post("https://[ENVIRONMENT].cloudax.dynamics.com/data/TestEntity", content);

    string token = null;

    yield return GetAccessToken((tokenResult) => { token = tokenResult; });

    result(token);

    www.SetRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
    www.Send();

    if (!www.isError)
    {
        string resultContent = www.downloadHandler.text;
        // Perform additional operations...
    }
}
```

Comment: Before making the HTTP call to your authenticated endpoint, can you check that you definitely have the Bearer token in the Headers?

Comment: Which API are you calling and are you sure the resource identifier / scope is correct in your request to /token?

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: @juunas I updated the thread with my code. I am not sure if I understand what you mean by "identifier", would that be the client_id? the scope that I'm using is https://graph.microsoft.com/.default, should I specify it somewhere else in the ERP side? thanks.

Comment: @DaveC I set it by calling SetRequestHeader() but during debugging, where do I see that value in UnityWebRequest object? FYI, I also tested the access_token in Postman, but it did not work either, so I'm think that I really need to get an authorization token first, and then get the access token. Any idea is welcome, thanks!

Comment: @shingo Code added, thanks!

Comment: did you make sure there is no `www.error` in the first request and you are getting an empty string? and what does `result(token);` do?

Comment: I don't know anything about oauth and `Bearer` but with `Basic` I had to use base64 encoding like `"Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1").GetBytes($"{username}:{password}"))` to get it to work .. maybe you have to do the same for the token?

Comment: @derHugo the www shows "401 unauthorized". I think I need to use Bearer for OAuth2.0.

Comment: yes you have to ... what I ment is maybe you have to use it like `"Bearer " + Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1").GetBytes(token)`

Comment: @derHugo Same result. 401 unauthorized.

Comment: Do not encode tokens. The problem is the scope you are using means the token will be for MS Graph API, not Dynamics.

Answer (score 0):

The resource is different for the token and the API call. In the token request, the resource is `https://graph.microsoft.com`, it's not your destination API. You should request the token for your destination API.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on that? do you mean that i should not use graph.microsoft as the scope? if so, what should I add instead? Thanks for the help!

Comment: The scope should be app ID URI of the API you want, affixed with the `.default` suffix. For the Microsoft Graph example, the value is `https://graph.microsoft.com/.default`.